# Draw in rect not getting called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, core-graphics

So I have a chart drawing view. It is in a view controller that is presented as modal. The problem is that drawInRect doesn't get called. Why is that? The view is set up in Interface Builder, and initialized ...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    minVal = [self.delegate minValue];
    maxVal = [self.delegate maxValue];
    noSteps = [self.delegate noSteps];
    stepVal = [self.delegate stepValue];
    data = [self.delegate dataArray];
    formulaName = [self.delegate formulaName];
    self.titleLabel.text = formulaName;

    // draw the chart
    self.chartView = [[PSChartIOS alloc] initWithFrame:self.chartView.bounds andChartType:PSChartTypeColumn];
    [self.chartView setDataSource:self];
    [self.chartView setChartTitle:@""];
    [self.chartView setPanOXAxis:YES];
    [self.chartView setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.chartView setStartAtTheEnd:NO];
    //[chart setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [self.chartView loadData];
    [self.chartView setNeedsDisplay];
    // NSLog(@"autoresize mask :%d",self.view.autoresizingMask);

//    [self.view addSubview:self.chartView];
//    [self.chartView addSubview:chart];




    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

All the delegate methods are called, so the view has it's data... it never draws...
I have a felling that the problem might be self.chartView.bounds .. but that should just return the bounds is set up in IB...

Found the problem :

```
 NSLog(@"the bounds %@",NSStringFromCGRect( self.chartView.bounds));
```

returns

```
the bounds {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

I thought that it will get the bounds from IB .. apparently not

Comment: seems t work if I manually create the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commented out the line that puts the PSChartIOS view into the view hierarchy.

```
//    [self.view addSubview:self.chartView];
```

I would bet that once you did that everything will be good.

Also you frame doesn't make sense.  Create the view with a frame like

```
CGRectMake(0,0,200,200).
```

This will test to make sure you can see a Chart at 200x200 in the view controller's view.

Comment: I uncommented that line... nothing happened

Comment: @user1028028 Take a look at my edits to create the frame different.

Comment: yes, that was the problem... I needed to create the frame manually

Answer (score 0):

I can't see `drawInRect` method call in your code.

If you are expecting `setNeedsDisplay` to call it. Then it can't be called automatically. If you have created your own method then you need to call it explicitly.

However it will call `drawRect`.

EDIT:

You did a typo **there is no method called `drawInRect:` it is `drawRect:`**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    // only draws what is specified by the rect parameter
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Shouldn't that method (drawInRect) be called when the view is about to appear ? I call setNeedsDisplay to "force" the view to redraw ...

Comment: Found the problem:  NSLog(@"the bounds %@",NSStringFromCGRect( self.chartView.bounds)); returns the bounds {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} .. WTF ... if I set up the view in IB , shouldn't it get the bounds from there????

Comment: yes it can get the framerect even from IB or programatically implemented

Comment: it just doesn't get the frame from IB , need to figure out why ... could it have something to do with AutoLayout?